# Copy text of error msg from circled-X in Eclipse source editor

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to fix literally hundreds of XML validation errors in a Java webapp using Eclipse. Researching them with Google has been excruciatingly painful, because up to now, this has been my workflow:

1. Open Google in a browser.
2. Click in the Eclipse editor tab where the error (shown as an icon at the start of the line that's a red circle with a white "X") is located, mouseover, and try to memorize a chunk of it.
3. Click on the search form in the browser, and attempt to replicate the chunk from memory.
4. Repeat steps 2-3 until the text in the search form matches the text Eclipse ephemerally displays on the screen. Usually, something like:

"cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'description' No Child element is expected at this point."

(that's just one error out of thousands, shown for illustration. I copied it from memory in 5 or 6 chunks)

At the moment, it's blowing my mind that there doesn't appear to be any easy way in Eclipse to do something like right-click the error icon & choose "copy error description"... or at least display it in some way that will survive giving another window the input focus so I can read it while typing it into the search form.

I know there **has** to be a better way to do this.

I suspect the error descriptions are present somewhere on the "Problems" tab, but I literally have almost 10,000 Errors & Warnings there, and no obvious way I'm aware of to sort or filter them. Is there maybe some keyboard modifier + mouse action that will allow me to click the red/white X icon and have Eclipse take me directly to the error on the Problems tab?

Comment: The Problems view has extensive filtering support - click the small down arrow at the top right of the view.

Comment: Hmmm... my "Problems" view doesn't appear to have that (screenshot added, above). If it matters, I'm running Spring Tool Suite v 3.7.0.RELEASE, based on Eclipse Mars (4.5.0).

Comment: A small triangular arrow next to the minimize and maximize buttons.

Comment: The only thing I see in the upper-right of the Problems tab besides the minimize and maximize buttons is a greyed-out icon that shows "Focus on Active Task" when I mouseover it (see screenshot above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question, and I feel for you, there is a slightly easier way. I'm running Eclipse Kepler but I suspect this will work for you too.

Roll your mouse cursor over the problem x icon in the editor gutter (if you're showing line numbers it will be in that area), wait till the tool tip displays the error message, then quickly move your cursor over the tool tip and click within the text, then you can select all (Ctrl + a) and copy (Ctrl + c), then paste wherever the error description.

Comment: Cool, that's exactly what I needed to know. Thanks! :-)